# running Hadoop software on office computers (when they are idle)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, hbase

Is there a project which helps setup a Hadoop cluster on office desktops, when they are idle?

I'd like to experiment with Hadoop/MR/hbase but don't have acces to 5-10 computers. The computers at work are idle after hours and are connected to each other through a very high speed connection. What's more, data on these computers stays within our network so there is no privacy issue.

In order for this to work I need a fairly light weight monitor running on each machine. When the computer has been idle for X hours, it will join the cluster. If the user logs on, it has to drop out of the cluster and return all CPU/memory back.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: I highly recommend Amazon AWS / Elastic Map Reduce. You can set up fairly powerful Hadoop clusters quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use task scheduler to detect idle state and then start/stop a hadoop vm with virtual box or vmplayer. Or you can write a powershell script that does start stop based on resource usage.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea windows scheduler could schedule with respect to idle time! Others ma find this useful: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/agent_idle_time.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Do we have any references or link where we can establish and use virtual box in each of the Desktops which are having 4 Gigs of RAM and setup Hadoop Cluster. It would be a good experimental lab. Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop is not a computation grid it is a more a data grid (see slide 9 in [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/steve_l/my-other-computer-is-a-datacentre-2012-edition)). The point is that with hadoop that data is spread over the cluster and thus the data has to be stored on the computers. The time it would take to copy the data over/remove it when they're not idle would probably not be worth it - you'd be better off using hadoop in the cloud (amazon,Azure etc.)

Comment: I won't be removing data. Shutting down a node when the computer is being used by a human just means that I will temporarily remove the node from the hadoop cluster. When the computer is available to hadoop, the node will start up and re-join the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like Condor: http://research.cs.wisc.edu/condor/

Comment: Thanks HaloWebMaster. I already have a Condor solution at my university (greedy.epfl.ch). It is great, but I would like to use something like HDFS, so I am looking for is a Hadoop implementation.

Comment: You could perhaps use the [Parrot virtual file system](http://ccl.cse.nd.edu/software/parrot/) in the Condor jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at Virginia Tech's Project Moon http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2012/05/project_moon/

Comment: Is their system available outside Virginia Tech? I could not find a link to download it...

Comment: Renaud, you might want to contact the Lead PI of Project Moon Wu-Chun Feng http://people.cs.vt.edu/~feng/ to check whether its available for download

Answer (score 0):

Look at solutions like [NEREUS](http://www-nereus.physics.ox.ac.uk/about_overview.html) which is a good MPC solution in Java

Comment: Thanks Grooveek. I already have a similar solution at my university (greedy.epfl.ch). What I am looking for is a Hadoop implementation.